# Decomposition of $p\mathcal{O}_K$, $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{15}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$. I want to determine the decomposition of $p\mathcal{O}_K$ for a prime $p$ in $K$.

The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{15}$ is $F(X)=X^2-15$ and $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{15}]$. Now, to find the decomposition of $p\mathcal{O}_K$ we will consider the factorization of $F(X)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. The possibilities are:

1. $X^2-15$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$
2. $X^2-15=(X-a)(X-b)$ with either $a=b$ or $a\not= b$

For $p=2,3,5$ I found factorizations of the form $(X-a)^2$ but generally, this is where I got lost and confused. How is all this tied to the original question?

Comment: Do you know that for abelian extensions (quadratic fields have abelian Galois group) the splitting of prime ideals lying above $p$ only depend on $p \bmod N$ where $N$ is the conductor of the field ? (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_field#Prime_factorization_into_ideals) and a course about the Artin map in cyclotomic fields). Otherwise you can generalize the [Fermat two squares theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat's_Two_Squares_Theorem) which is the same problem in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Comment: @user1952009 I am assuming the form $p\mathcal{O}_K=\mathcal{p}_1^{e_1}\cdot...\cdot\mathcal{p}_r^{e_r}$ where $r\in\{1,2\}$. For $r=1$ we would get either $e_1=2$ and $[\mathcal{O}_{K/\mathcal{p}_1}:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]=1$, or $e_1=1$ and $[\mathcal{O}_{K/\mathcal{p}_1}:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]=2$. For $r=2$ it would be $e_1=e_2=[\mathcal{O}_{K/\mathcal{p}_1}:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]=[\mathcal{O}_{K/\mathcal{p}_2}:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]=1$. I guess the first case corresponds to $X^2-15=(X-a)^2$, the second to $X^2-15$ irreducible, and the third one to $X^2-15=(X-a)(X-b), a\not=b$.

Comment: Since the extension is Galois of degree $2$, there are $3$ possible cases : $(p)=\mathfrak{p}^2$ (ramified) and $X^2-15  \equiv (X-a)^2 \bmod p$, or $(p)=\mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2$ (split) and $X^2-15  \equiv (X-a)(X-b) \bmod p$,  or $(p)$ is prime (inert) and $X^2-15$ is irreducible  $\bmod p$. The [conductor/discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_reciprocity_law#Examples) of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$ is $60$, so ramify occurs only for $p=2, 3 $ or $5$, and inert or split depends only on $(\frac{60}{p})$.

Comment: also $g(X)$ is an irreducible factor of $X^2-15 \bmod p$ iff $\mathfrak{p} = (p, g(\sqrt{15}))$ is a prime-maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{15}]$ containing $(p)$.

Comment: @user1952009 In fact I believe inert or split depends on $(\frac{15}{p})$ (coming from $X^2-15=X^2-a^2(mod~p)$), but $(\frac{15}{p})=(\frac{60}{p})$, so the result is the same. Thanks!